# message popup on mouse hover

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am developing a website in wordpress.There is a menubar at the header.Now what i want is ,when i hover the mouse over the menu item i should get a message popup .

[image]

in above case it should be "services at Umang" when mouse is placed over services menu item.

the following is the css code for mouse hover

```
    #access li a:hover 
    {
      text-decoration:underline;        
     }
```

Any one has idea regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the title-attribute

```
<a href="#" title="Message">Hover!</a>
```

Or google for "jquery tooltip"

http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Use the `title` HTML attribute. It would cause a popup to occur after hovering after a certain short amount of time.

It's also native and semantic.

**[Live Example](http://dabblet.com/gist/3088869)**

Comment: Can you please include an example in your answer? So he could understand in better way.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<element onmouseover="alert('text')">qwe</element>
```

or

```
<element onmouseover="this.innerHTML='someText'"></element>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with some div which has `position: absolute` and then make sth like:

**CSS**

```
#access li a:hover #someAbsolutePositioningDiv
{
  display: block;    
  position: absolute;
  top: some value;
  left: some value;
}

#someAbsolutePositioningDiv
{
  display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="access">
 <li>
   Text
   <div id="someAbsolutePositioningDiv">Some other text</div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the li to position:relative, inside of it place another element (the popup-message) and give it position:absolute and display:none, and position it with left, top etc (like: left:10px;top:-50px;) to the position you want. Then set it to display at hover:

```
li:hover .popup-message {display:block;}
```